# how can I enter multiple lines in an OSX terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

How can I enter multiple lines in a terminal ?
I would like to do the same thing as when I do shift + enter in chrome.

Comment: Apparently shift+enter in the Chrome console allows you to embed a newline in a command without submitting it for evaluation just yet. In many situations the shell already knows you are in a context where the command line isn't finished, such as when you are in a string or in a control block such as `if`, `while`, or `for` without a corresponding `fi` or `done`

Comment: try Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Only `Esc`+`Return` works for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

End your line with a backslash (`\`), hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and continue typing on the next line.

Keep in mind that if you need spaces between the parts of your command, you need to enter them explicitly, e.g.:

```
ls \
-la
```